# Using Observable of array in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have the following code:

```
  get items():Observable<MenuItem[]>{

  let items: MenuItem[] =  [
      {
       label: "incidents_dialog_tab_actions_measures_defined"
      },
      {
       label: "incidents_dialog_tab_actions_measures_with_supplier_agreed"
      },
      {
        label: "incidents_dialog_tab_actions_measures_are_implemented"
      },
      {
        label: "incidents_dialog_tab_actions_measures_are_effective"
      }
  ];

  return  Observable.from(items).mergeMap( obj => this.commonModel.translate(obj.label)).bufferCount(items.length);
}
```

and `this.commonModel.translate(obj.label)` returns an observable.

In my template I use it like this `[model]="items | async"`, items should be an observable of an array that contains the translation in the format `{ label: translation}`. How can I achive this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `.map()` to `this.commonModel.translate` to continue transforming the returned translation and give it the desired shape:

```ts
Observable.from(items)

 // Call the translation service for each item.
 .mergeMap(item =>
   this.commonModel.translate(item.label)
     // Store the translation in an object with the shape you want.
     .map(translatedLabel => ({ label: translatedLabel }))
 )

 // Use this to put back all translated items in a single array again.
 .toArray();
```

Comment: Where does toArray() come from ?

Comment: It's a RxJS Operator: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-toArray. Without it, when you subscribe you will receive each translated item one by one. It might be what you want but usually it's more convenient to receive only ONE array holding ALL the translated items.

Comment: There might be other errors in your code. Please provide a Plunkr and I'll take a look at it.